# why extern changes mangling to C?

Tags: c++, name-mangling

```
const unsigned abc = 5;
```

```
$ g++ -c -o ec.o ec.cpp
$ nm ec.o 
0000000000000000 r _ZL3abc
```

So far so good: `abc` has C++ mangling.

Now:

```
extern const unsigned abc;
const unsigned abc = 5;
```

```
$ g++ -c -o ec.o ec.cpp
$ nm ec.o 
0000000000000000 R abc
```

Mangling changed to C...
Then:

```
extern "C++" const unsigned abc;
const unsigned abc = 5;
```

```
$ g++ -c -o ec.o ec.cpp
$ nm ec.o 
0000000000000000 R abc
```

Mangling is still C, even though
I explicitly asked for C++ one.
Why that happens?

Comment: Name-mangling was invented for functions to allow for function overloading. It makes no sense to mangle variable names to begin with.

Comment: Also note the difference between `r` and `R` for the `nm` output: `r` typically means the variable is *local*, i.e. it's not exported and have internal [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage). `R` means it's *global*, i.e. it's exported and have external linkage.

Comment: _"Mangling changed to C"_ the compiler decides what's C++ name mangling. If it compiles as C++, it's C++ name mangling.

Comment: Good point about "r". When the same code is compiled with gcc and not g++, it would have "R" in both cases. So seems in an absence of extern, c++ compiler implicitly adds "static" and also changes mangling to c++. So I can assume the ABI only supports C mangling for global variables and the c++ mangling is used as an implementation-specific decision for static variables, and c++ compiler is allowed to add "static" when there is no "extern"? Well, too many "ifs" for a consistent theory, but getting there. :)

Comment: The default variable linkage is external in C, internal in C++.

Comment: Both local/internal `_ZL3abc` and external `abc` are mangled names.